# Как правильно пользоваться анонимными функциями php

Tags: php

Вот класс в котором инициализирую функцию

```
class test {
     public $products;
     public function __construct() {

           $this->products = function () {
               echo 'work!';   
           };
           $this->products();
     }
}
  $t = new test();
```

При таком использовании происходит ошибка

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method import::products()
```

Comment: Разные варианты решения вашей проблемы http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535330/calling-closure-assigned-to-object-property-directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем случае можно воспользоваться функцией [call_user_func()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.call-user-func.php). То есть вместо

```
$this->products();
```

использовать

```
call_user_func($this->products);
```

Comment: Можно. Осталось только понять - зачем.

Comment: @Ипатьев, надо спросить у ТС.

Comment: @Ипатьев учусь, все в жизни пригодится